# How to find MLE of this pdf?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Consider the density function f(x)=$\frac{3}{\lambda}$ $x^2$ $e^\frac{-x^3}{\lambda}$  where x > 0, and λ > 0.

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of λ for a random sample of size n.

My attempt:
[image]

Do you think that this is correct?

Thanks for comments.

Comment: You're off by a factor of $-1$ (since clearly $\lambda$ cannot be negative).

Comment: So, do you mean that -nlogλ should be nlogλ?

Comment: No, it seems that you forgot to multiply by $-1$ when computing the derivative of $$-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3}\lambda. $$

Comment: Oh, right! I got your point. Thank you so much for correction!